# Importing wordpress content into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import one site into Wordpress multisite using phpmyadmin. I have tested on another single site and code imports. I change the wp_ to wp_g22_ and try importing into multi site and get this error:

SQL query:

> INSERT INTO `wp_g22_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES (252433, '_transient_jm_cats_d27300020302d47e080e7e962d68d506', 'a:47:{i:0;O:7:"WP_Term":12:{s:7:"term_id";i:398;s:4:"name";s:13:"Accommodation";s:4:"slug";s:13:"accommodation";s:10:"term_group";i:0;s:16:"term_taxonomy_id";i:418;s:8:"taxonomy";s:20:"job_listing_category";s:11:"description";s:248:"Whatever your budget, find **accommodation** in Herefordshire, Worcestershire, Gloucestershire, Monmouthshire, Shropshire & Powys. Our Guide2 covers hotels, B&Bs, self-catering, camping, glamping, farmhouses and more.\r\n\r\n ";s:6:"parent";i:0;s:5:"count";i:124;s:6:"filter";s:3:"raw";s:9:"term_type";s:1:"0";s:14:"term_font_icon";s:1:"0";}i:1;O:7:"WP_Term":12:{s:7:"term_id";i:437;s:4:"name";s:10:"Activities";s:4:"slug";s:10:"activities";s:10:"term_group";i:0;s:16:"term_taxonomy_id";i:457;s:8:"taxonomy";s:20:"job_listing_category";s:11:"description";s:418:"The ultimate guide[...]

MySQL said:

> Documentation 
>    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:47:{i:0;O:7:"WP_Term":12:{s:7:"term_id";i:398;s:4:"name";s:13:"Accommodation"' at line 2

Comment: Are you sure this database dump is valid?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, new to this, thank you

Comment: If it's not importing due to syntax errors I'm wondering if it's valid. How are you importing?